# amplify init fails constantly

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I don't know whats really wrong with my amplify. I run `amplify init` and  get this error message. I have downloaded my amplify cli using npm and have successfully run 'amplify configure'.

```
init failed
InvalidSignatureException: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/apps

host:amplify.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:79ec4b759220a7b1d454721bb2c7e1350dccbd691853e5ed1b3c92bec21dbc29
x-amz-date:20210121T154050Z

host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
79ec4b759220a7b1d454721bb2c7e1350dccbd691853e5ed1b3c92bec21dbc29'

The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20210121T154050Z
20210121/ap-south-1/amplify/aws4_request
b150344845c2c575fd957d63172173a367f2bacf0e817764a02e5b20d03c3811'
```

Comment: "Check your AWS Secret Access Key" -- did you validate your credentials?

Comment: Yes  have checked  them over and over again. They are correct

Comment: Also i checked the credentials in .amplify folder, and matched the credentials saved for a profile. They were correct

Comment: how can I check the credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I finally found out what was bugging me for last three days. A whitespace ( ).
Yes!

I had my folder inside the user with a whitespace in it, as in "First Last". Instead what I should have done is changed my folder name inside my `C:\Users\First Last` to `C:\Users\FirstLast` before starting, and then try to install my amplify CLI using the command `curl -sL https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-cli/install-win -o install.cmd && install.cmd` and proceed as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/start/install).

To change the name of the User folder in windows 10, I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XASJTN8Sr1I) great YT! video

Answer (score 1):

On Mac:
I was also getting the same error while using the [aws amplify CLI tool](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/start/install) in my nodejs project.

Like @miraquee noted above about the issue being a white space. I suspected that I also had the same issue. What I did to start clean was:

1. Delete the local `.aws` folder in my home folder on mac to start clean

```
rm -rf ~/.aws/
```

2. Ran `amplify init` again. This time when reaching the step where it asks you to create an IAM user, which subsequently takes opens your web browser to finish the creation of the new IAM user, I was very careful about copying in the `Access Key Id` and `Secret Access Key`
   [image]

This time when I went through the flow in the CLI it worked.

If you want to see a video of these steps, checkout this YouTube video built by one of the engineers on the AWS amplify team
[image: AWS Amplify CLI walkthrough]

- Youtube video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWbM5DLh25U